# Python can't find Blender Module

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, blender, bpy

I've built [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) as a python module on Ubuntu. Ran `make install` which updated the site-packages. Running `python3 -m site` returns the following:

```
sys.path = [
    '/root/blender-git/build_linux_bpy',
    ... a bunch of other paths here ...
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

When I try and do a simple `test.py` that imports the Blender module `bpy`, I get a `no module named 'bpy'` error. Not familiar with python import rules or how to add a module, so it's no clear what I'm doing wrong. I also tried setting the sys.path explicitly but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Linux, but Blender's Python is a unique install.
The only way I've found to install 3rd party modules is to open Blender (as admin in Windows) and run the following commands:

```
from pip._internal import main
main(['install','pandas'])
```

This will install whatever 3rd party module to your python version in Blender.
I hope that helps.